# How do I tell Subversion to treat a file as a binary file?

Tags: svn

How do I tell Subversion (svn) to treat a file as a binary file?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It is possible to manually identify a file located within a repository as *binary* by using:

```
svn propset svn:mime-type application/octet-stream <filename>
```

This is generally not necessary, as Subversion will attempt to determine whether a file is binary when the file is first added.  If Subversion is incorrectly tagging a certain type as "text" when it should be treated as binary, it is possible to configure Subversion's [auto-props feature](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto) to automatically tag that file with a non-text MIME type.  Regardless of the properties configured on the file, Subversion still stores the file in a binary format within the repository.

If Subversion identifies the MIME type as a "text" type, it enables certain features which are not available on binary files, such as *svn diff* and *svn blame*.  It also allows for automatic line ending conversion, which is configurable on a client-by-client basis.

For more information, see [How does Subversion handle binary files?](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#binary-files)

Comment: Where practical, I would rather specify the specific (binary) MIME type for the file rather than the generic `application/octet-stream`, which at a minimum it can be found with [`file --mime-type -b filename`](https://askubuntu.com/a/3397/549800) or looking online for the file extension.

Answer (score 21):

From page 367 of the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.pdf)

> In the most general sense, Subversion handles binary files more gracefully than CVS does.
>   Because CVS uses RCS, it can only store successive full copies of a changing binary file.
>   Subversion, however, expresses differences between files using a binary differencing algorithm,
>   regardless of whether they contain textual or binary data. That means all files are
>   stored differentially (compressed) in the repository.
>
> CVS users have to mark binary files with -kb flags to prevent data from being garbled (due
>   to keyword expansion and line-ending translations). They sometimes forget to do this.
>
> Subversion takes the more paranoid route. First, it never performs any kind of keyword or
>   line-ending translation unless you explicitly ask it to do so (see the section called “Keyword
>   Substitution” and the section called “End-of-Line Character Sequences” for more details).
>   By default, Subversion treats all file data as literal byte strings, and files are always stored
>   in the repository in an untranslated state.
>
> Second, Subversion maintains an internal notion of whether a file is “text” or “binary” data,
>   but this notion is only extant in the working copy. During an svn update, Subversion will
>   perform contextual merges on locally modified text files, but will not attempt to do so for
>   binary files.
>
> To determine whether a contextual merge is possible, Subversion examines the
>   svn:mime-type property. If the file has no svn:mime-type property, or has a MIME
>   type that is textual (e.g., text/*), Subversion assumes it is text. Otherwise, Subversion
>   assumes the file is binary. Subversion also helps users by running a binary-detection algorithm
>   in the svn import and svn add commands. These commands will make a good
>   guess and then (possibly) set a binary svn:mime-type property on the file being added.
>   (If Subversion guesses wrong, the user can always remove or hand-edit the property.)

Hand editing would be done by

```
svn propset svn:mime-type some/type filename.extension
```

Comment: How do you do this on import? I.e., __before__ it gets into the repository? The use case I have is a file that svn will not import because it thinks it's ill-formed text (inconsistent line-endings).  But it's **test data**, so the file is **intended** to have inconsistent line-endings....

Answer (score 15):

Basically, you have to set the mime type to octet-stream:

```
svn propset svn:mime-type application/octet-stream <filename>
```

Answer (score 13):

If 'svn add' guesses the incorrect type and gives you an error like the following:

```
svn: E200009: File 'qt/examples/dialogs/configdialog/images/config.png' has inconsistent newlines
svn: E135000: Inconsistent line ending style
```

then the workaround is to add the file without properties and then set the properties in a second step:

```
svn add --no-auto-props qt/examples/dialogs/configdialog/images/config.png
svn propset svn:mime-type image/png qt/examples/dialogs/configdialog/images/config.png
```

Answer (score 8):

For example:

```
svn propset svn:mime-type image/png foo.png
```

Answer (score 4):

Although Subversion tries to [automatically detect](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#binary-files) whether a file is binary or not, you can override the mime-type using [svn propset](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re23.html).
For example, `svn propset svn:mime-type application/octet-stream example.txt`. This will make your file act as a collection of bytes rather than a text file. See also, the svn manual on [File Portability](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.mime-type).

Comment: Just to update your link for the automatic detection algorithm:
http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#binary-files

Answer (score 3):

If using tortoise svn in Windows, right click on the file and go to properties.  Click on new and add a new property of type svn:mime-type.  For the value put:  application/octet-stream

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#binary-files), you can use svn propset to change the **svn:mime-type** property to **application/octet-stream**

Answer (score 2):

svn looks for a mime-type property, guessing it is text if it doesn't exist. You can explicity set this property, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.forcvs.binary-and-trans.html

Answer (score 0):

It usually does this by default for you, but if it isn't you need to look into file properties and propset.